# WIX won't execute command

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have a WIX installer and I need to run two commands:

```
net localgroup administrators reviewer /add
```

and

```
appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='Reviewer'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='Reviewer'].processModel.userName:reviewer /[name='Reviewer'].processModel.password:reviewer
```

the second command is quite complex and involved square brackets and single quotes

First command must run from `C:\Program files\mycompany\myfolder`, the second one from `C:\windows\system32\inetsrv`

Here my two WIX custom actions:

```
    <CustomAction Id="AssignUserToAdminGroup" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"
      ExeCommand="net localgroup administrators reviewer /add" 
      Return="check"/>

    <CustomAction Id="AssignUserToIISapp" Directory="IISFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"
      ExeCommand="appcmd.exe" 
      Return="check"/>
```

As you may have noticed I removed a lot from the second command just to make sure I don't have to deal with square brackets and single quotes (it's just a test)

Here the fragment which specifies the directories where such commands should be launched from (`INSTALLFOLDER` and `IISFOLDER`)

```
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="Company" Name="mycompany">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="myfolder" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
         <Directory Id="System64Folder" >
        <Directory Id="IISFOLDER" Name="inetsrv"  />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

This code compiles fine but I get an error while installing, the appcmd.exe could not be executed. What's causing the problem?

Comment: Can you add the msi installation logs?

Comment: @zaitsman oops! not at work now... I'll upload the log on tuesday!